# Is $\sqrt{x}$ uniformly continuous in $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Tags: calculus, uniform-continuity

We are given this function:
$f:R^+\rightarrow R,x\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$.

We  need to prove that this function is uniformly continuous.
My proof is this one but i'm not sure is it complete and right.

Let pick up $\epsilon>0$  and $\gamma>\epsilon^2$.
We need to find $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in R^+$ with $|x-y|<\gamma$

Without loss of generality we can assume that $x<y$.

We see that $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\rightarrow|x-y|<\gamma$

$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|^2\leq|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|=|x-y|<\epsilon^2\rightarrow||\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|<\epsilon$

Since $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|<\epsilon^2$
This show that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $f:\mathbb R^+\rightarrow \mathbb R$

Comment: $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq|\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|$ tells you that you can say $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|^2\leq|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}|=|x-y|<\epsilon^2$. Your conclusion follows by definition. You were close, but it seems as if you found a solution online and didn't quite understand it.

Comment: $|f'(x)|=|\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}|\le \frac12$ hence f is uniform continuous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very unclear what you are doing:

1. What is $\gamma$ and why did you set $\gamma > \epsilon^2$?
2. I assume that $\gamma$ is the $\delta$ from standard definitions. Even then, you have the line:
   $$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\to |x-y|<\gamma$$
   which makes no sense. What you *SHOULD* do is start with the fact that $|x-y|<\gamma$ and finish with $|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|<\epsilon$, but that's not what I see here.
3. You say that $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|^2 = |x-y|$, which is just plain **wrong**.

Answer (score 3):

Use the inequality: $|x-y|\geq|x+y - 2\sqrt{xy}|$

Fix $\delta > |x-y|≥0$

$\Rightarrow$ $\delta > |x-y| = |x+y - 2y| = |x+y - 2\sqrt{yy}| ≥ |x+y - 2\sqrt{xy}| = |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|^2$

Hence, $|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| < \sqrt{\delta} = \epsilon$

Since, $\epsilon$ only depends on $\delta$, we have a bound independent of the values of *x* and *y* and only dependent on their distance. Hence, we have uniform continuity.